# Apache Kylin not able to load models/configuration

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, kylin

I'm new to hadoop,hive, hbase and kylin. I tried to install thoose first three, and it's seems to be working.

After that I tried to install apache kylin, run the sample.sh and success.

After running the script I restart and open the web interface. Some page cannot be opened ex: /cube, /models, /admin/config

The problem is: I can see there are 5 tables created in hive, and also 2 cubes created. But when I open in web gui, the models is in loading-state and I cannot build the cube.

[image]

When I try to build the cube
[image]

I cannot find any infomative log (Or maybe there is one, but I don't know about it)

kylin.log
https://pastebin.com/TUZkQepa

hadoop-hadoop-namenode-master.log
https://pastebin.com/T8eNt3PY

hadoop-hadoop-secondarynamenode-master.log
https://pastebin.com/iMJDNFfU

yarn-hadoop-resourcemanager-master.log
https://pastebin.com/TGwJWTRF

hbase-hadoop-zookeeper-master.log
https://pastebin.com/Ym6eky5h

hbase-hadoop-master-master.log
https://pastebin.com/p1ygfw4W

Here is the configuration for hadoop
(yarn-site.xml)

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
        <value>master:8030</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
        <value>master:8031</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
        <value>master:8032</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://master:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
      <value>/home/hadoop/tmp</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

---

Configuration for hbase
regionservers

```
slave2
```

hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://master:9000/hbase</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>/home/hadoop/datadir</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>master,slave2</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

---

Configuration for hive
hive-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://master:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
    <description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    <description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>root</value>
    <description>user name for connecting to mysql server</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>gwudainget</value>
    <description>password for connecting to mysql server</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.cli.print.current.db</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>Whether to include the current database in the Hive prompt.</description>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

For kylin, I use default configuration, because I don't really know what to do with the kylin configuration.

What i use:
hadoop 2.7.5 binary
hbase 1.2.6 binary
hive 1.2.2 binary
kylin 2.2.0 source (I just add logs)

Comment: You probably shouldn't leave the defaults if you want it to connect to external components of the cluster

Comment: @cricket_007 can you give me some links/guidance/example for that? So I know which settings I have to change, since I'm new into this. Thanks

Comment: I haven't configured kylin in over a year. I would hope the documentation at least tells you what properties need to be set to connect to the Hbase master(s), and maybe a Zookeeper quorum